# Unable to call update method on a datasource

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have a simple SQLDatasource that I have created in asp.net. the datasorce is calling stored procedures for both insert and select. the bound data controls are in a formview but the data source is outside of the formview. I am attempting to call the update method when the save button is called.  But when I run the page, I am getting the error:  error BC30451: 'SqlValuations' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

My code is very simple.

```
Public Sub Save_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
      SqlValuations.Update()
End Sub
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Posting your markup and any relevant code behind would help.  The error you get is pretty specific and gives you a couple of things to check.